# Ajax POST returns full partial view inside Bootstrap panel body

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ajax to call controller actions and load items inside a table in a bootstrap panel. The full panel-group is inside a partial view. I just want the order data returned and the panel body to populate with the newly filled view model, but the whole partial view is being reloaded into the selected panel body.

[image]

There are three panels, so I have 3 POSTs:

```
 $("#evaluation-panel-heading").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EvaluationOrders","Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
          if (data) {
              $("#evaluation-panel-body").html(data);
          }
        }
    });
});
$("#dfc-panel-heading").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("DfcOrders","Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $("#dfc-panel-body").html(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
$("#wip-panel-heading").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("WipOrders","Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $("#wip-panel-body").html(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Controller Action's:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EvaluationOrders()
    {
        using (var entity = new Entities())
        {
            var atp = User.Identity.Name;
            var ordersInEvaluation = entity.uspGetOrdersInEvaluation(atp).ToList();
            var viewModel = new AtpMobileViewModel
            {
                OrdersInEvaluation = ordersInEvaluation
            };

            return PartialView("BucketOrders", viewModel);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DfcOrders()
    {
        using (var entity = new Entities())
        {
            var atp = User.Identity.Name;
            var ordersInDfc = entity.uspGetOrdersInDFC(atp).ToList();
            var viewModel = new AtpMobileViewModel
            {
                OrdersInDfc = ordersInDfc
            };

            return PartialView("BucketOrders", viewModel);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult WipOrders()
    {
        using (var entity = new Entities())
        {
            var atp = User.Identity.Name;
            var ordersWip = entity.uspGetOrdersWIP(atp).ToList();
            var viewModel = new AtpMobileViewModel
            {
                OrdersWip = ordersWip
            };

            return PartialView("BucketOrders", viewModel);
        }
    }
```

The first panel body for reference:

```
<div id="evaluation-panel-body" class="panel-body">
    @if (Model != null && Model.OrdersInEvaluation != null)
    {
    <table class="footable">
         <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Description</th>
                  <th>Client</th>
              </tr>
         </thead>
        @foreach (var order in Model.OrdersInEvaluation)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@order.OrderDesc</td>
                <td>@order.db_CustID</td>
            </tr>
            }
    </table>
   }
</div>
```

I am just trying to populate the table not reload the whole partial view in the selected panel-body. I am having trouble figuring out how to populate the view model and reload the table in the div without returning the whole partial view. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are returning the sameBucketOrders  partial view each time.  I believe you may need a partial view for each return in the controller.

Comment: What kind of element is the AJAX trigger `#evaluation-panel-heading` and is it within a form?

Comment: `#evaluation-panel-heading` is not within a form, it is just the anchor that opens the first panel

Comment: Then you need to prevent default link action.

Comment: Why would that be? The default link action is just to open the panel

Comment: why would you reload the panel every time someone clicks on the heading?

Comment: I switched up the code after this question to only load the panel if the panel-body is empty

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, this is pretty straight-forward. You have one partial that has content you only want *some* of the time. Therefore, you either need to break it into two partials, such that you have one with the panel layout, and another with panel content (the layout partial can load this partial), or you need to only include the panel content in the partial and just have the panel layout directly in the view.

Either way, the endpoint that responds to your AJAX request needs to return a partial that only contains the panel content, which is not happening now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Partial View for the content. If all order has the same field, you could use one Partial View for all the content, if not, you will need to create a partial for each content.

in summary:
You need a View for the Layout and other for the Content ( or one per each content ).